# Why does the Google Play Store reject my Nativescript APK for not being 64bit compliant?

Tags: android, google-play, 64-bit, release, 32bit-64bit

Google Play now has new rules regarding 64 Bit compability - all APKs that have binarys need to provide 64 bit versions too. I tried to submit my nativescript app, that has a 64 bit binary but the warning shows up ...

This release is not compliant with the Play 64-bit requirement

[image: https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/images/develop/64bit/console_warning.png]

Why? I have got 64 bit support:

Native Platforms listed in Google Play

Native Plattformen
**arm64-v8a**, armeabi-v7a, x86

Google even generates 64bit apks from my aab.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that since nativescript provides x86 binaries, Google Play also requires x86_64 binaries. Generating these binaries can be disabled in the app.gradle by adding the ndk block as specified here - so only arm binaries will be generated.

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'your.application.id'
    generatedDensities = []
    ndk {
      abiFilters.clear()
      abiFilters.addAll(['armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a'])
    }
  }
  aaptOptions {
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
  }
}
```

Then the x86 package will not be generated when building a release apk or aab and google won't complain about missing 64bit stuff.

[Related Nativescript Github issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/4330)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Paul!